# How to custom ToolbarComponent of Material-UI KeyboardDatePicker in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi currently I am using React, Material-UI, KeyboardDatePicker.
You can see the code in:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rt1f1?file=/index.js

```
import "date-fns";
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  // The first commit of Material-UI
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-dialog"
          label="Date picker dialog"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
          views={["year", "month", "date"]}
        />
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

What I want to do is when I click the calender Icon, if I click the date tool bar(which is current date in the UI), I want the interface changes to month selection interface.

I am planning to custom the datPicker using ToolbarComponent.

from the Material-UI official documnet (https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker), found out I got that I need to enter some code like this:

> ToolbarComponent={ComponentClass<ToolbarComponentProps<unknown, DateTimePickerView>, any> | FunctionComponent<ToolbarComponentProps<unknown, DateTimePickerView>> }

But hard to understand ToolbarComponent I should enter.
How can I customize the prop of the calendar? please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass a function to the ToolbarComponent API and return a JSX.

```
ToolbarComponent={() => <Box>HELLO, CUSTOM TOOL BAR</Box>}
```

The above jsx will be rendered above the calendar.